# Testing multiple instances of mongdob on OS X

Tags: macos, testing, mongodb, clojure

I am attempting to test the monger mongodb driver for clojure (which is essentially a wrapper around the java driver)

I start my mongodb instance, which works fine:

```
./mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2/bin/mongod --port 28017 --dbpath /data/db/
```

But connecting to it via the shell fails:

```
./mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2/bin/mongo -port 28017
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:28017/test
DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Error: Error during mongo startup. :: caused by :: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 
127.0.0.1:28017 query: { whatsmyuri: 1 } shell/mongo.js:86
exception: connect failed
```

Is there some crucial step I am missing to get this working?

Comment: I just tried to do the same thing in the shell and it worked fine.  What happens when you try to use a different port?

Comment: are you sure the server is up?  check its log, make sure that /data/db exists, etc.

Comment: server is up:
[websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 29017
[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 28017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are connecting to the web admin console of the other server.

Try

```
mongod run --config <path_to_mongod.conf> --port 9080
```

and

```
mongo -port 9080
```

Comment: Ah ... the default port is 27017, which maps to admin of 28017!! I used the same pattern to increment the second server's port and voila! Nothing works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Looking at [the docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell), they are specifying the address to connect to with the first positional argument, not the `--port` flag. Perhaps you can try the argument version instead?

I do notice that it *seems* to connect to the right port, but then tries to run the query against the wrong port - perhaps it's a bug where the `--port` flag is not being properly propagated?

Other than that, I'm not sure what could be going on...

Comment: Using the explicit "./mongo 127.0.0.1:28017" fails with the same error.

Comment: The port number in my example was due to copy/paste change as I was playing with different options.